# Best index for dimension table?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I was wondering what the best index would be for a table which tracks changes over time?

```
employee_id, supervisor_id, manager_id, department_id, location_id, effective_date, expiration_date
```

I would be joining the employee ID to other tables, but I want to make sure that the accurate (for that slice of time) columns are pulled.

```
WHERE t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id 
AND t1.date >= t2.effective_date
AND t1.date < t2.expiration_date
```

Would I want an index on my fact table on employee_id and date? And then on the dimension table on employee_id, effective_date, and expiration_date?

Also curious if having an index on (employee_id, effective_date, expiration_date) would be preferable compared to a separate index per column?

Comment: If you are going to use query stated above, then it's better to create index on (employee_id, effective_date, expiration_date) columns combined.

Comment: Yes - is there another (more efficient) query that I should look into? It is important that things are mapped correctly during certain periods of time and there are frequent changes.

Comment: I don't think there is anything we can optimize with this query rather than indexing and we have already discussed about index.

Comment: Great to hear. I should be all set. If you would post an answer I can accept and close this out then. Ideally, with some background information about why the combined index would be best in this situation (it is not clear when I should do that and when I shouldn't)

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use query stated above, then it's better to create index on (employee_id, effective_date, expiration_date) columns combined.